# Print the number of characters of every file name using for loop in Mac terminal

Tags: bash, macos, for-loop, terminal

I need to print the number of characters of every file name in a directory using a for loop in the terminal (Mac). This directory is called lorem and it has 3 files: at.txt, lorem.txt and sed.txt.

Up to now I have done this:

```
lorem sarahr$ ls
at.txt      lorem.txt   sed.txt
FILES=/Users/sarahr/lab-bash-master/lorem/*
lorem sarahr$ for i in $FILES
> do
> echo '$FILES has' | wc -c
> done
      11
      11
      11
```

Eleven three times is the result, but it's not what I need. Could you help me?

Comment: `cat * | wc -c`

Comment: Loop through files with print * if you have to use a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have a directory `lorem` with the following file structure:

```
lorem/
├── at.txt
├── lorem.txt
└── sed.txt
```

The following bash script should work as required when run inside the folder:

```
for file_name in * ; do echo ${#file_name} ; done
```

**Output:**

```
6
9
7
```

**Documentation for [`${#parameter}`](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-expand.html#parameter)**:

> The length in characters of the expanded value of *parameter* is
> substituted. If *parameter* is `'*'` or `'@'`, the value substituted is the
> number of positional parameters. If *parameter* is an array name
> subscripted by `'*'` or `'@'`, the value substituted is the number of
> elements in the array.

Answer (score 1):

First, `cd` to the directory where your files are located. Change the loop you showed to count the length of the desired file names (`$file` variable). Use `echo -n` to suppress the terminal newline, which adds 1 to the file name length.

```
cd /Users/sarahr/lab-bash-master/lorem
for file in * ; do
    echo -n "$file "
    echo -n "$file" | wc -c
done
```

Output:

```
at.txt 6
lorem.txt 9
sed.txt 7
```